# VoiceChannel id

Tags: c#, discord

I'm new to c# and I don't know how to realize one idea. My bot should send the id of the voice channel to the user who sent the command is connected to.

```
ulong GuildId = Context.Guild.Id;
```

like this, but with voice channel

Comment: This isn't a valid question.   Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GuildUser` in order to check for the voice channel property. 
Something like this:

```cs
if (Context.User is IGuildUser guildUser)
{
    var voiceChannel = guildUser.VoiceChannel;
    // do something with voice channel
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood what the error was and I will try not to allow it anymore :)